# Am I building these reference and pointer functions correctly? And if so, how do I explicitly call my destructor?

Tags: c++

Reference function:

```
// the getDept() function shall be defined as a reference function. That is, a call to this function will copy the
// member variable m_iDeptID into the int variable referenced by the function argument
void EmployeeRecord::getDept(int& d)
{
    d = m_iDeptID;
}
```

Pointer function:

```
// the getSalary() function shall be defined as a pointer function. That is, a call to this function will copy the
// member variable m_dSalary into the int variable pointed to by the function argument
void EmployeeRecord::getSalary(double *sal)
{
    *sal = m_dSalary;
}
```

Destructor (I don't have any delete statements, or anything, in the function):

```
// destructor - cleans up and deallocates any memory that pointers within this class may have referenced to
EmployeeRecord::~EmployeeRecord(){}
```

My attempt at explicitly calling the destructor:

```
EmployeeRecord Employee1;
Employee1.~EmployeeRecord();
```

So my questions are:
(1) Are my reference and pointer functions consistent with their descriptions?
(2) If they are, what code should I put into the block of my destructor so that I can call the destructor explicitly, and it successfully "cleans up and deallocates any memory that pointers within this class may have referenced to" (if there is, in fact, anything I need to put in the body of the destructor)?

Comment: I think this `*sal = m_dSalary;` should be `*sal = *m_dSalary;`

Comment: This code makes no sense.  If you're creating an object in the normal way, then why are you explicitly calling the destructor?  (Doing so can only lead to bad things.)  And what does this have to do with your member functions?

Comment: Why to call the destructor? Your object is local (on the stack) --> the destructor will be called ones your function returns

Comment: As an aside: you might want to check if `sal == nullptr` before you try to write anything to it.

Comment: @Marcin  m_dSalary isn't a pointer

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so I shouldn't explicitly call the destructor in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In turn:

1. `getDept(int &d)` is consistent with its description, but `getSalary(double *d)` isn't quite: the description says it should copy the value into the **int** variable pointed to by the function argument.

   `getSalary` then should take a `int *` argument, instead of a `double *` argument, and the method should perform the appropriate cast. (This does seem a bit of an odd specification though — sure it wasn't meant to say double rather than int?)
2. From the information at hand, there is nothing to clean up, presuming the member variables are just `int`s and `double`s and so on. Are there any members that are pointers?

Comment: No member variables are pointers. There are two character arrays, but I don't think I have to delete those (and when I tried I got a break case anyways). Also I think the description is supposed to be double... That would be odd for it to be type int.

Comment: The destructor should release any resources that have been claimed by the instance of the object; so if those character arrays were allocated on the heap with `new []`, they should be deallocated with `delete []`; if they were allocated with `malloc` they should be deallocated with `free`; etc. If they are simply array member variables, then there is nothing to do :)

Comment: Awesome! So all of my functions are built correctly according to the commented out specifications? And I don't have to call my destructor explicitly?

Comment: It's an extremely rare situation where you need to call a destructor explicitly. They are invoked automatically when the object falls out of scope or is explicitly deleted. Given the information that is visible here in the question, it looks like you are good to go!

Comment: Thanks, you've been a huge help.